# javascript function to detcte the regex for string along with number

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this code for checking if it's a string please use some regex to extract only numbers, but in some cases i do have this:

```
Column1     Column2
($75.00)    $0.00 PayPal Email Declined
```

```js
var intVal = function(i) {
  console.log(i);
  return typeof i === 'string' ?
    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
    typeof i === 'number' ?
    i : 0;
};
```

what regex needs to modify so i get the numbers values only

Update #1

Because i am doing datatables calculation in tfoot, i am using this code

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api();
            
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
            };
            
            ColumnThreeTotal = api
                .column(3, {page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
           
            $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+ColumnThreeTotal
            );
```

it has two problems, first it is showing of all rows instead of the current page, and second the results are coming as:

```
$1.000092378555231e+74
```

Comment: Try : /[^0-9]/g

Comment: thanks, but using the above, i am getting the results as: `$1.000092378555231e+74 `

Comment: How? Will You share Your code

Comment: ok here i am editing my original question

Comment: i added it in my original question